# SoapUI 5.4.0 works extremely slow on macOS High

Tags: soapui, macos-high-sierra

I'm using SoapUI 5.4.0 in my MacBook Pro with macOS High Sierra (10.13.3).

The application works very slow (especially the graphics) and sometimes it hang on and I need to force restart.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 11):

- From your Applications folder, select the SoapUI app.
- Right-click and select `Show Package Contents`.
- Navigate to `Contents/java/app/bin` path and locate `soapui.sh` file.
- Edit the file in a text editor.
- Uncomment the line `# JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true"`.
- Save the file.
- Open SoapUI.

***Note (based on Vlad's comment):***

- You may also need to add `-Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true` into `Contents/vmoptions.txt`.
- You should see `browser component is disabled` when you start SoapUI, which is a signal that the option has worked out.

Comment: You may also need to add "-Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true" into "Contents/vmoptions.txt". You should see "browser component is disabled" when you start SoapUI, which is a signal that the option has worked out

Answer (score 7):

You have to disable the browser component of SoapUI. (The thing that is displaying the those valuable product information all the time.)

To do so set the system property `soapui.browser.disabled=true`.

A detailed how-to can be found here:
http://shariati.me/how-to-fix-soapui-speed-issue-on-macos/

Comment: Since the link in the answer no works, here is how to disable the browser component.
Uncomment the line `# JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true"`  located in `/Applications/SoapUI-5.5.0.app/Contents/java/app/bin/soapui.sh`. Just replace the path with the location you have installed your SoapUI

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you to increase the heap size for the tool. [Here](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/working-with-soapui/improving-memory-usage.html) is the documentation for your reference.

> SoapUI is rather memory intensive, especially with default settings for logging, etc. If you are running more lengthy functional tests or load tests you might well bump into an OutOfMemory error. Fortunately, there are several things that can be done to minimize the risk for running into this error.
>
> ## 1. Adjust Memory Settings
>
> This doesn't really solve the underlying problem, but if you have large WSDLs, requests, attachments, etc the default settings in "bin\soapui.bat", "bin\soapui.sh", "bin\soapUI-Pro-5.2.0.vmoptions" for Windows or "Contents/vmoptions.txt" for Mac won't be sufficient.
>
> Open the corresponding file in a text editor and change the line
> `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx256m -Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties`
> to use higher values for the max allocated size, for example:
> `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx768m -Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties`
> The exact value is hard to say, it depends of course on your system setup, other applications running, etc. You can set it to half the amount of available memory, for example on a machine with 2 GB of ram that would be 1024. Remember that if you are running a 32-bit operating system (for example Windows XP), then you wont be able to allocate more than approximately 1.5Gb, so there is no use in setting the value higher then that.
> If you run into PermGen errors (for example if you are using a lot of groovy scripts), then you might need to adjust that setting as well, add a `-XX:MaxPermSize` setting to the above line:
> `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties`
> If you want to dig into all possible memory-related options, check out [Joe Mocker's Collection of JVM Options](http://blogs.sun.com/watt/resource/jvm-options-list.html).

Comment: Your solution doesn't improve my problem